# How do I install Chromium on Linux Mint using Software Manager?

Tags: software-installation, chrome, linux-mint

I intalled Linux Mint 10 and would like to use it instead of Windows as a desktop OS. The first thing I would like to do is to install the Chromium web browser.

So I start *Software Manager* and then goes to *Chromium* and there is a button *Install* that I click on. The the progress bar at the bottom of the Software Manager goes up to *5%* before it goes down to *0* againg, and nothings happens.

How do I install Chromium using Software Manager or any other graphical software in Linux Mint 10?

---

The reason to do it only by using graphical tools, was to compare the usability with Windows. Now I tested the commands that NES suggested, `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` but it failed with this messages:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe chromium-browser-inspector all 7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.169 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe chromium-browser-inspector all 7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.37 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe chromium-browser amd64 7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.37 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-inspector_7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.37 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_7.0.517.41~r62167-0ubuntu0.10.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.37 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: you probably want to check the log, or use a command line (BTW it's not that scary) and post the output

Comment: did you follow the advice: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? Are there problems with your internet connection?

Comment: @NES: No, I didn't. But I did it now, and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Would you kindly untag this 'debian'?

Comment: @jmtd: I have retagged my question now.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

give the installation via terminal a try:

1. open terminal
2. run the command: sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

**alternatively you can add the chromium repository via commandline to your sources like this and install it from there:**

1. open terminal
2. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the first command but it failed. See my update. I don't want to use private repositories, but thanks anyway. I can live with Firefox.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: @Falmarri Thanks running sudo apt-get update fixed it for me.

Comment: on mint20 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable
Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support focal''`